# How to remove participant profile link from participant name in moodle chat?

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle version 2.8, I have added chat activity in course. I wants to remove participants profile link on participants name which display right side of chat window.

So how can I display only name of participants without any link on its name?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

The file you're looking for is **`/mod/chat/lib.php`**

I've not tested this but I think the line you're looking for is line 1037 (By [GitHub](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_28_STABLE/mod/chat/lib.php) count). You can find that and then change it from

```
 $item['url'] = $CFG->wwwroot.'/user/view.php?id='.$user->id.'&amp;course='.$course->id;
```

to

```
 $item['url'] = '#';
```

---

and then if you want to remove the URL from the list of users as well, go to line 1257 and change it from

```
$userlink = new moodle_url('/user/view.php', array('id' => $chatuser->id, 'course' => $course->id));
```

to

```
$userlink = '#';
```

There are more references to the profile page peppered around this file (seven reference in total). There's also another reference at the bottom of view.php for the module.

> Please note that modifying those files means you'll be creating a
>   branch from the module's core and is not advised.

Comment: It take url of same page and open in new tab.

Comment: Try $item['url'] = '#'; instead of $item['url'] = ''; and $userlink = '#'; instead of $userlink = '';

Does that work for you?